# Error while attaching IAM policy and launching instance in AWS from AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pem, key-pair

You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: KvgfJLnYPXk96wSuddXsUXevnofWQul4lixB8jrmzyL-YFUsUoxWhx6ovSj5zJMRZOWr6cnIX5oitWHGpNO8HJ9q7PhJsBenClv5zSN-TlZ6HHUyQaXGxUNTlz2c21N0VIhVR2P0M0hfzu_PsYyKu7YcL7HruNRunx0aUtIs5MB6WwQrNkasM8DWizLVotw_M2xKVDH3SJbrXXThkjrHFOUhdUnTB8J9e74XrgcK5_uicbYEsR4cTz6IRdiw0y1EV9RJd9lZnkFXVrenqpCPZ-FG-8AZ3mDqAZkMMbOOThURKEZ-vIjIIgZsudCW6gCKgHWe8SUHfNeSVLRc2hNdqb8K8dugc8kS0A1Fmd7f7_29qK2EXGztIwU77bVryWvVeAbzdQU5SqNaYZpkCVbR27MMZnID-YleyykVKO1ZiGeiNBFdqjKp8wiinsRrASZZ1y2VOTDB2j8CuA7Ym_zTlH4f86lkqXRiK-R6LmHsGrYam6Wy3rahAHcHV56pW4fVG-QRMm5Uid4BWR9Pij5bq8OeJ8avjySMm50bdn7yERkc82dM3MvK-dMuV1rPGgRpEpiCfnqfFI5RUJ_d0M_hj-vd7UYfAIfyXqnN1GhrTpY20wgE6fUJGgslojUKOtfMjVHsDH00xocTW96BsZcDlFksMZ9Q4pzXTocbshLB_deX8jklJVSbUuTELxfMGcahnFi8DH2nNHus6Ni9SrtamVNtPf1PHt7cYQ0ANEgX3-zayVXVh1XzDfRyImbsHmTIMVv_7v4dxPVDRC1qNs4KNaVH7fUT1Zzv4FW91Awmf78wVfE--XrREvOaA6ZJBsf66639wcn_5Bd3LBWJnQ4mhii2Y_1QqdfMOeUhflTgBVWYIbQL9KDDWi8982RoryP4CHJVFhpVUiDbsAG8s0a02Dq5wojMQ-to6-LJc_mGMmhuupTT9aXzT9DympkJ56T48KVWtaVuOfVklD4vZ1p2f_TLXgxd-Awlbqiqbpq4s1gaiMPcnuOAltAnU3nSoISIP2RPHILTIbQKMIlwKZYOozj7G8517053pdmYe5vdIntjmxO3_ggTf18KwA47sPE-KBgriFsOnJfh-uG2xvyupIxR5Ea9KX-IeHzCb-CykSpMNBUWx7uC4MdIiov6DmmLp1uARYmL3fNBd_yFna-xXrENT2eoe2lJgcwlatLK0zwlH2wATJJG9zHA5AyoJt4kOpoG9DvYFfKEdJXE7h44ZOhwPnWtRkXLqpZXOSFQEfebpWZ2zYb8jQ

trying to attach SMM role in IAM and use system manager to gain access to a Windows instace - whose key is lost

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode the message to see what the problem is. [This doc](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-not-auth-launch) explains how to do that.